# Passing rails hash map to Controller (from form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash, parameters

I am developing a rails application for a client. In a nutshell, it is for monitoring the progression of PhD uni students. One of the main functional requirements was for the user to be able to fill out reports online. The issue I am having is with one of the forms.

I am allowing the number of questions per form to be completely unrestricted, so I am using dynamic symbols to store the answers to the questions, and pass those answers to the controller in a hash. Here is a snippet of the code from the form, and the controller method:

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
        <div class="field">
            <!--Question Label -->
            <%= s.send(:label, "Question #{q.question_number}") %> 
            <!--Link to delete question -->
            (<%= link_to 'Remove', {:controller => "report_details", :action => "delete_question", :question_to_delete => q.id}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'form-link', :method => "post" %>)
            <!--Question text box -->
            <%= s.send(:text_area, "qu_hash[question#{q.question_number}]", :rows => 3, :cols => 60, :value => q.question) %>
            <!--New Question Button -->
            <%= link_to '>> Insert Question Here <<', {:controller => "report_details", :action => "add_question", :position_to_add => q.id}, :method => "post" %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

My issue is with with the line below  I think. I will explain why below, but here is my controller method (accessed by submitting the form).

```
def save
    questions = params[:report_detail][:qu_hash]
    ReportDetailQuestion.where(:report_detail_id => @report_detail.id).each do |q|
        q.update_attributes(:question => questions["question#{q.question_number}".to_sym])
    end

    redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully updated.'
end
```

The error I am getting is this:
    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

```
questions = params[:report_detail][:qu_hash]
ReportDetailQuestion.where(:report_detail_id => @report_detail.id).each do |q|
    #Error occurs on the below line
    q.update_attributes(:question => questions["question#{q.question_number}".to_sym])
end
```

The hash is not a part of the database, it is being used to update entries in the table of report questions (seperate to the report table). This error is being caused because the hash is not being submitted from the form (on the error screen - where it shows the params passed to the controller, the hash is not present).

Also, I am unsure how to permit this hash through the "white list" of the object, so if someone could help with that it would also be helpful (for now I am just permitting everything, so that won't be the issue. The field just isn't being submitted for some reason).

If you need more information let me know!
Cheers

Comment: It would appear your questions hash is nil so trying to access the question number fails.  So the actual problem is on `questions = params[:report_detail][:qu_hash]`

Comment: This is the list of params passed from the form, :qu_hash is not in the list of params

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"9XBEgifII3Kf3Oaq0gqDn0ysidEtuaTJYMr5qUK+sdM=",
 "report_detail"=>{"title"=>"PH010",
 "description"=>"Confirm PhD title and supervisory team; confirm if ethics is required and the expected ethics submission date to PGR admin.",
 "three_year_deadline"=>"2",
 "four_year_deadline"=>"2",
 "six_year_deadline"=>"4",
 "role"=>"student"},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem I will advise you to use nested forms which is more suitable for this case mainly for user experience. For that, you need to create a question model first.

you can follow [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) which explains well how to do...

Not sure it is what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks, That looks really useful - I think I'm too late into the project to completely change the way I'm doing it. I've managed to fix the bug I had somehow - I have literally no idea how - I didn't really do anything to change it, haha! Next time I'll definitely do this though, looks way more efficient.